# Why I'm I getting "undefined is not a function" in the following ES6 for loop?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

The input:

> first line
>
> second line
>   third line
>
> fourth line

The code:

```
let res = str.split('\n\n')
for (let result of res) {
    res = `<p class="blockquote">${res.replace(/^> /gm, '')}</p>`
}
console.log(`text: ${res}`)
```

`str.split('\n\n')` outputs `first line,second line third line,fourth line`. What I expected.

Now I want to use the `for` loop to take each item and surround it with `p` tags. However, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I'm not very experienced with ES6. Is there something wrong with the loop?

Comment: What are you trying to get in the end? an array of the four strings wrapped in the blockquote tags? can you show the desired output?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there's something wrong. Two things.

```
res = `<p class="blockquote">${res.replace(/^> /gm, '')}</p>`
```

res is initially an array, so it has no `replace` method. That's the error you get.

The other thing, once you fix that (replace `res` with your loop variable `result`), is that you assign the resulting string to `res`. I'm not sure what you expect, but I guess it won't work that way.

Comment: Assigning to `res` is fine since it's only fetched one time at the start of the loop, though it is a little weird style-wise.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I know it doesn't break the loop, but it overwrites each result so that in the end `res` only contains the last string, not all of them. I can only assume since OP hasn't clarified, but the most obviously desirable outcome would be to map each string to the string with tags.

Comment: Ah gotcha, my mistake then.

Answer (score 3):

The problem in assigning new value to `res` variable inside `for` loop. So after first loop step we will have another value in `res` and loop will end;

Try this code:

```
let str = 'first line\n\nsecond line third line\n\nfourth line';
let res = str.split('\n\n')

for (let result of res) {
    let i = `<p class="blockquote">${result.replace(/^> /gm, '')}</p>`
    console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: Assigning to `res` is fine, though a little weird. It's just the `.replace` call that is wrong.